# reading multiple lines from TCP stream

Tags: java, tcp

looking to build a tcp listener which will read information from a connection and respond with some data.

I've got the program working on a single line input but when I send multiple lines it doesn't work.

Here is the code I was using

```
try {
    Socket clientConnection = null;
    clientConnection = serverSocket.accept();
    clientConnection.setSoTimeout(5 * 1000);
    String tmpLine=null;
    BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    for (tmpLine = inFromClient.readLine(); tmpLine != null; tmpLine = inFromClient.readLine()) {
        searchLine += tmpLine;
        logMsg = "DBUG : T" + threadName + " readline : " + searchLine;
        stubLog.addMessage(logMsg, coreProperties.getLogger(),"DEBUG");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    logMsg = "ERRR : T" + threadName + " : tcpStubWorker: error in getting data : " + e.getMessage();
    stubLog.addMessage(logMsg, coreProperties.getLogger(),"ERROR");
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

When I send in this message from a harness:

```
String logonMsg = "msg: 0800    P3A^SNAT2 >>> S3A^SNAT204        15/10/12 16:55:07.00 rec: 001021\n"
+ "bit 007: 1012165507  \n"
+ "bit 011: 498432  \n"
+ "bit 033: (11)59501100554  \n"
+ "bit 070: 001  \n"
+ "bit 100: (11)59503646554  \n";
```

I get this in the logs:

```
DEBUG com.stubby.tcp.tcpStub  - 14:33:43:494 - DBUG : T00000026 readline : nullmsg: 0800    P3A^SNAT2 >>> S3A^SNAT204        15/10/12 16:55:07.00 rec: 001021
DEBUG com.stubby.tcp.tcpStub  - 14:33:43:509 - DBUG : T00000026 readline : nullmsg: 0800    P3A^SNAT2 >>> S3A^SNAT204        15/10/12 16:55:07.00 rec: 001021bit 007: 1012165507  
DEBUG com.stubby.tcp.tcpStub  - 14:33:43:510 - DBUG : T00000026 readline : nullmsg: 0800    P3A^SNAT2 >>> S3A^SNAT204        15/10/12 16:55:07.00 rec: 001021bit 007: 1012165507  bit 011: 498432  
DEBUG com.stubby.tcp.tcpStub  - 14:33:43:534 - DBUG : T00000026 readline : nullmsg: 0800    P3A^SNAT2 >>> S3A^SNAT204        15/10/12 16:55:07.00 rec: 001021bit 007: 1012165507  bit 011: 498432  bit 033: (11)59501100554  
DEBUG com.stubby.tcp.tcpStub  - 14:33:43:552 - DBUG : T00000026 readline : nullmsg: 0800    P3A^SNAT2 >>> S3A^SNAT204        15/10/12 16:55:07.00 rec: 001021bit 007: 1012165507  bit 011: 498432  bit 033: (11)59501100554  bit 070: 001  
DEBUG com.stubby.tcp.tcpStub  - 14:33:43:603 - DBUG : T00000026 readline : nullmsg: 0800    P3A^SNAT2 >>> S3A^SNAT204        15/10/12 16:55:07.00 rec: 001021bit 007: 1012165507  bit 011: 498432  bit 033: (11)59501100554  bit 070: 001  bit 100: (11)59503646554   
ERROR com.stubby.tcp.tcpStub  - 14:33:48:627 - ERRR : T00000026 : tcpStubWorker: error in getting data : Read timed out
```

Any ideas why the for loop is failing to recognise on tmpLine != null?

I suppose I could decrease the timeout and make that error a warning but that doesn't sound quite right!

Thanks.

thanks for feedback, the peer is using this code to send the data

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("10.52.88.102", 8888);
DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
outToServer.writeBytes(logonMsg + '\n');
modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
System.out.println("From server: \"" + modifiedSentence +"\"");
clientSocket.close();
```

but still getting the error :( so i suspect I'm not closing the connection correctly??

Comment: You don't need to initialize a variable you assign in the very next line.

Answer (score 2):

The peer isn't closing the connection, and your read loop will only stop when he does.

Comment: Just as I said. The peer can't close the socket until the server responds, and the server can't respond until the peer closes the socket, because it's stuck in its read loop. You need to do your responding inside your read loop.

Comment: Or else shutdown the client socket for output after sending the request.

Comment: Thanks guys, makes sense now. I was trying to write a "generic" stub which needs the entire message to process but my understanding of TCP behavior is clearly lacking. I will need to adapt the  to the needs of the client application as they come on board. Hopefully it'll all be single line messages :)